# rsync a list of directories with absolute path in text file

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I have a text file containing a list of directories with its **absolute path**

```
$ cat DirectoriesToCopy.txt

/data/Dir1
/data/Dir2
```

I want to use rsync to copy all these directories preserving its absolute path to another location.

I tried the following rsync command, but it doesn't work

```
rsync -avr --include-from=DirectoriesToCopy.txt --exclude='*/' --exclude='/*'  /  /media/MyDestination/
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to transfer `/data/Dir1` and `/data/Dir2` including their contents to `/media/MyDestination/Dir1` and `/media/MyDestination/Dir2` ? Or do you want to include the `/data` part? How large is this list, is it too big to simply list those entries on the command line? Anyway, your `--exclude` statements prevent the recursion.

Comment: I want to transfer all the files inside those directories as well. There are many files in that directory, so I would like to avoid creating another text file with all the filenames.

Comment: I would like to keep my full path like `/media/MyDestination/data/Dir2/` . I added the --exclude to prevent other directories and files in / from getting copied.

Comment: In cases where the list of directories are not very large, i guess the following option is more easier `rsync -av $(cat DirectotiesToCopy.txt) /media/MyDestination/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
rsync -av --include-from=DirectoriesToCopy.txt --include /data/ --exclude='/data/*' --exclude='/*/' / /media/MyDestination/
```

You need to include /data/ explicitly, you could also have added that to the list in the file. Then exclude all other directories (order is important with includes/excludes).

Note that your usage of `-r` was redundant as that's included in `-a`.

EDIT:
You could also accomplish the same result with:

```
rsync -av --relative /data/Dir1 /data/Dir2 /media/MyDestination/
```

It's not rsync that's forcing you to do difficult things just to copy a couple of directories, it just gives you multiple ways of doing the same thing; in some cases going the include/exclude way may be more suited, here I'd do the --relative thing above (without `--relative` you'd end up with `/media/MyDestination/Dir1` and `/media/MyDestination/Dir2`, with the `--relative` the whole source path is copied to the destination).

Comment: Thank you that worked. I am a little surprised that one has to define such careful sequence of filters for simply copying a list of directories using rsync. For example, if my list of directories were not under one common directory /data/ but was instead spread around many locations, the filters to define becomes quite complicated.

Comment: See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. So if my list of directories is not very huge, I could use the --relative flag as shown below. `rsync -av --relative $(cat DirectotiesToCopy.txt) /media/MyDestination/`

Comment: Yes; keep in mind `--relative` is just another option.

Comment: I would use `$(cat DirectoriesToCopy.txt | xargs)` instead to make sure the arguments that are one on each line are actually passed as arguments to rsync

Comment: Whether the arguments are on a separate line or not makes no difference whether you do `$(cat DirsToCopy.txt)` or `$(cat DirsToCopy.txt | xargs)`, the shell interprets all white space as equal (see `$IFS`) . Also lookup OOUC ;-)

Answer (score 10):

> I want to use rsync to copy all these directories [from a list] preserving its absolute path to another location

Don't use `--include` or `--filter` variations, as that will just confuse things. Instead, use `--files-from=_filename_`. (If you do, make sure you do *lots* of testing.)

1. Create the directory list in a file, one directory/file per line.
2. Use rsync's `--files-from=` with the above file.
3. Use `--relative` / `-R` option to make sure the source pathnames are copied at the end of the destination.
4. Even if you have the `-a` option, also include `-r`. From the man page:

   > In  both cases, if the -r option was enabled, that dir's entire hierarchy would also be transferred  (keep  in mind that -r needs to be specified explicitly with --files-from, since it is not implied by -a).

Complete command:

```
rsync ${DEBUG:+-nv} -arR --files-from=<list_of_files.txt> <top-level-dir>  <target-dir>
```

(the files in *list_of_files.txt* must be relative or found in *top-level-dir*)

(if DEBUG is set, rsync merely prints out what might have been copied.)

Comment: This is what I needed! However "--include-from" should be "--files-from". Also I used "--list-only" to see a preview of what RSYNC will do before actually letting it work.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer. `--include-from` will also work, but then what I said about `-r` is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

The [rsync manual](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) warns about this scenario (section “Include/exclude pattern rules”):

> this won't work:
>
> ```
> + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
> + /file-is-included
> - *
> ```
>
> This fails because the parent directory `"some"` is excluded by the `'*'` rule, so rsync never visits any of the files in the `"some"` or `"some/path"` directories. One solution is to ask for all directories in the hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: `"+ */"` (put it somewhere before the `"- *"` rule), and perhaps use the `--prune-empty-dirs` option. Another solution is to add specific include rules for all the parent dirs that need to be visited. For instance, this set of rules works fine:
>
> ```
> + /some/
> + /some/path/
> + /some/path/this-file-is-found
> + /file-also-included
> - *
> ```

In your case, I think the simplest approach would be to preprocess the list of directories to include so that whenever you include `/path/to/foo`, you also include all the parent directories (`/path/to`, `/path`, `/`), and also include subdirectories of the original directories (`/path/to/foo/***`), and after all this have a rule that excludes everything not previously listed (`*`).

```
<DirectoriesToCopy.txt awk '
    {print "+ " $0 "/***"; while (sub(/\/+[^\/]+\/*$/, "/")) print "+ " $0}
    END {print "- *"}
' >rsync-rules.txt
rsync -avr --include-from=rsync-rules.txt  /  /media/MyDestination/
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and script to create the rules file. I understand the issue now. I still feel it would have been nice for rsync to have an option like --dirs-from=DirectoriesToCopy.txt as a short cut to all the complicated filters.